# Hiding user input into a nested bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Bit of an odd one I know.

We have an install script provided to us by the product developers, we implement this product across multiple servers but the default install script they provide is only designed for a single server. As such we have created a shell script with SSHs across all the servers and runs the script, the issue is that the inputs into the default script are hidden but by running it through our script they are no longer hidden.

Here's the gist of it:

`sshCmdString=echo "./INSTALLSCRIPT.sh CONFIG-PARAMETERS`

`ssh -T $sshuser@$HOST $sshCmdString`

I'm wondering how I would go about altering the ssh script to hide the input again?

I know read -s hides input within a bash script but I've found that this hides all the outputs of running the script if I put in before/in the command to run the script on the other servers.

Is there another option out there that will hide inputs but display outputs/logging from the script?

Comment: You should remove the `echo` from the string, just have the string in quotes (probably not your error, but still)

Comment: What does "input" mean in your question.  Are there user inputs (i.e. user typing on the keyboard) and you are not seeing that?  Or do you mean some other kind of input (or output)?

Comment: Yes, input would be user typing on the keyboard after a prompt. At the moment it is showing what is typed in and I want it to not to be shown.